# Kiel diri @ en Esperanto?

Tags: pronunciation

Mi rimarkis ke mi tute ne scias kiel diri @  en Esperanto kaj mi guglis, sed nenion trovis pri tio.

I noticed that I don't know how to say @ in Esperanto. I searched the internet, but I can't find an answer.

Answer (score 6):

En retpoŝta adreso, oni kutime diras **"ĉe"**.

Laŭ la libro [Kauderwelsch Band 56: Esperanto - Wort für Wort](https://web.archive.org/web/20210918164417/https://www.reise-know-how.de/de/produkte/kauderwelsch-buch/esperanto-wort-fuer-wort-255) kaj [laŭ vikipedio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliko_(apartigilo)) la nomo de la signo "@" estas **"heliko"** (kiel la besto:)

[image: foto de helika besto]
Foto CC BY 2.0 [macrophile](https://flickr.com/photos/macrophile)

[Laŭ ReVo, "heliko" estas "[n]eformala nomo de la signo @"](http://kono.be/cgi-bin/vivo/ViVo.cgi?pagxo=helik.#helik.0o.ascii) kaj [alia (do la formala?) nomo estas **"po-signo"**](http://kono.be/cgi-bin/vivo/ViVo.cgi?pagxo=po.#po.0_signo).

Comment: Dankon! Tio estas helpo por mi.